# Stop erlang qlc query at first matching entry

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How do I write a qlc query that traverses table until it finds the first matching entry? For instance, this query returns all entries in the table that match criteria:

```
qlc:q([E#stuff.data || E <- mnesia:table(stuff), E#stuff.type == 123]).
```

How to modify this or the qlc:e call to stop and return only the first matching entry? The motivation for this is performance - I'm not interested in all entries, just want to take a look at how entries of specific type look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a qlc `cursor` and `qlc:next_answers/2`, take a look at the example in [qlc:cursor/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/qlc.html#cursor-1).
It should look something like

```
QH=qlc:q([E#stuff.data || E <- mnesia:table(stuff), E#stuff.type == 123]).
QC = qlc:cursor(QH).
Result=qlc:next_answers(QC, 1). % Only return 1 answer
qlc:delete_cursor(QC).
```